# Custom line on a word

Tags: html, css

I try to put a line on only one word. With changing its size and its position.

**Here the result I would like to have:**

[image]

I tried to use a span with background-image but no success.

https://jsfiddle.net/XZKS/193u9dam/

And other problem, background-image don't work when using local image.

***My website arborescence:***

- _include

  - css

    - style.css
  - js
  - img

    - line.png

`background-image: url("../img/line.png");`

I hope someone could help me, thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/193u9dam/1/ - like that?

Comment: Not quite, the underline should on the word. I've resolved my problem with the pseudo-element "::after". Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.myWordWithLine {
  position: relative;
}

.myWordWithLine::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 24px; // your line height
  background-color: red; // your line color
}
```

Comment: Simply by using the pseudo-element "::after". I have complicated the task by wanting to use "background-image". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Method #01:**

You can use css `linear-gradient()` to draw this background:

**Steps:**

1. Create background image with `linear-gradient()`.
2. Adjust its size with css `background-size` property.
3. Place it at the bottom position of the element with `background-position` css property.

**Necessary CSS:**

```
.line {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 5px;
    background-position: left bottom 5px;
}
```

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.line {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 5px;
    background-position: left bottom 5px;
  
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<h3>MY <span class="line">BLOG</span></h3>
```

**Method #02:**

You can use `::before` OR `::after` pseudo element:

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.line {
    position: relative;
}

.line::after {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h3>MY <span class="line">BLOG</span></h3>
```

Comment: I will use the second method with "::after". And thank you for the trick with "linear-gradient"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this
http://codepen.io/B101844/pen/bgLPPb

html

```
<div class="main">MY
    <div class="blog">
        BLOG
        <div class="underline"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.main{
font-size: 30px;
color: #1c3d93;
font-weight: 900;
}
.blog{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.underline{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #91dfcf;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 7px;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 8px;
}
```